# What does the message "Too few services" mean?

Tags: cities-skylines

My industry buildings are warning me that there are too few services. What does this mean?

[image: too few services]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

After some testing myself, I discovered this message means your **industries are lacking one or more of your basic services** such as **fire protection, police, mass transit, etc.** Placing offices near polluting industries can cause the "Too few services" message because of low land value. What the message actually is saying is: there is something undesirable about coverage or the location. In my case it was fire:

[image: before]

This was my fire coverage before I added a fire station.

[image: after]

And this is after. The messages all disappeared within a few seconds. If you are getting this message, be sure to check all your overlays to see what they are lacking!

Answer (score 2):

For me it was transportation. I created a new bus depot in the industrial area and created new routes that connected all building and this went away. Also I placed a fire department but they only got rid of like 2 of the building that said “Too few services” this fixed all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I also just ran into a situation where mine was due to noise pollution from my nearby wind farm.  Upgraded my freeways to include a sound barrier and it went away.